# Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis

In my analysis class we are discussing integrable functions and I need help thinking through something. I don't want any answers, just what should I be looking at? (hints)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is always possible and enough to consider partitions of $[0,1]$, with omitting finitely many points in $[0,1]$ while calculating lower sum and upper sum over all possible partitions of $[0,1]$. It wont affect the  integral.

Comment: Like $P_n=P\cup(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: what is $P$? arbitrary partition?

Comment: simply you can take partitions of $[0,\frac{1}{2}) \cup ( \frac{1}{2}, 1]$

Comment: @GA316: No, this is wrong. First of all, you can only take partitions of closed iintervals.

Comment: we are considering partitions of $[0,1]$ which not containing $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a partition $P=\{a=x_0,..., b=x_n\}$ such that the interval $[x_{j-1},x_j]$ containing $\frac{1}{2}$ have length $<\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$ where $M=\sup_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)$:

$$|U(f,P)-U(g,P)|=|\sum_{i\not=j}[M_i(f)-M_i(g)]|+|[M_j(f)-M_j(g)]|\Delta x_j<\epsilon$$

From this try to conclude.